# I want to first input on EditText showing decimal format as output 2

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimalformat

Here I have a problem that it can not display the decimal format in text1, please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

int number1, number2 ;
EditText Text1;
TextView Text2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

            }
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###");

                     number1 = Integer.parseInt( Text1.getText().toString());

                     if (number1 > 0)
                     {

                         number2 = ((number1* 3) /100)+ number2;
                         Text2.setText(df.format(number2));

                     }

              }

    }`
```

Comment: Thank's for edited

Answer (score 0):

to show the decimal try this:

Change

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###");
```

for

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###.##");
```

and format the number in:

```
text1.setText()
```

If you just want to format an integer just:

```
text1.setText(df.format(your_integer_number))
```

By the way, edit your question to show what are you doing in text1.setText

UPDATE:

after the line:

```
Text2.setText(df.format(number2));
```

do the following:

```
int number=Integer.parseInt( Text1.getText().toString());
Text1.setText(new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###").format(number))
```

After

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("###,###,###");
```

add the following:

```
Text1.setText("40000000")
```

Comment: is not successful. text 1 will display on the first input number1, look at the example image

Comment: this:  Text1.setText(df.format(number1))  doesn't work??

Comment: Yes doesn't work. If I do as you are commanded, the results force close

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me the entire class?

Comment: I have obeyed your command, but the process works decimal format after a button is pressed. I want the process works decimal format before the button is pressed, such as a default calculator on the operating system kit kat 4.2 or later

Comment: sorry i mean kit kat 4.4.2, 4.2 is jelly bean